# Build and prettify JSON object

Tags: jquery, json, object

I'm attempting to build a JSON object using ajax requests, then print out the data all prettified so it's easy to read.

Here's what I have:

```
var url, data;
var shows = ["stranger things", "the night of"];
var json = {};

$.each(shows, function(i, show) {
  url = 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + show + '&type=series&plot=short'
  $.ajax(url, {
    complete: function(obj, status){
      data = $.parseJSON(obj.responseText);
      json.push(obj.responseText);
      console.log(data);
    }
  });  
});

var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify({shows: json}, null, '\t');
$("pre").text(jsonPretty);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/we1p7cqj/1/

The issue lies somewhere around `json.push(obj.responseText)`, but I can't figure out a fix.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have the object initialization wrong:
should be `var json = [];`

Also, since the ajax requests are asynchronous by default, the following code is executed at the same time, and at that time the value of `json` is empty object

```
var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify({shows: json}, null, '\t');
$("pre").text(jsonPretty);
```

So you can either make the ajax requests synchronous or check for the last show before you execute that code:

```
if(showsLength == i + 1){
    var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify({shows: json}, null, '\t');
    $("pre").text(jsonPretty);
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/we1p7cqj/4/

HERE the other approach (synchronous requests)

```
$.ajax(url, {
    async: false,
    complete: function(obj, status){
      data = $.parseJSON(obj.responseText);
      json.push(obj.responseText);
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/we1p7cqj/5/

> Ah, I understand now. Thanks for the help, Sam! Is there a way to
>   remove the slashes \"? – Jon 10 mins ago

The reason you see these slashed is because you are stringifying a string not an object, so to fix that you need to make it a json object when you push

```
data = $.parseJSON(obj.responseText);
json.push(data);
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/we1p7cqj/7/

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thanks for the help, Sam! Is there a way to remove the slashes \"?

Comment: I just updated the answer with a demo to show you what the reason is for these slashes

Comment: Ah, makes sense! Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

- You can't push into objects; you can push into arrays.

  ```
  var json = [];
  ```
- Your `.text(jsonPretty)` is coming too soon. Move it into the `complete` handler.